# tkinter - move shapes

Tags: python, tkinter, drawing, move

How do you move eyes in Python ( when the spirit turns left the eye remain on the right side). I tried with  c.move(eye,-10, 0) when i defined the left movement, I've tried also state hidden for the eye and created a left_eye with state normal,but it doesn't work.
Thank you.

```
from tkinter import *
HEIGHT = 500
WIDTH = 800
window = Tk()
window.title('Fetita arunca mingea')
c = Canvas (window, width = WIDTH, height = HEIGHT, bg = 'grey')
c.pack()
school= c.create_rectangle (200, 50,600, 150, fill = 'orange')
school_window1 = c.create_rectangle (250,80, 300, 100, fill= 'yellow')
school_window2 = c.create_rectangle (360,80, 420, 100, fill= 'yellow')
school_window2 = c.create_rectangle (500,80, 550, 100, fill= 'yellow')
body =c.create_polygon (0, 450, 250, 450, 100, 240,fill ='blue')
head = c.create_oval (50, 250, 150, 150, fill = 'ivory')
eye =c.create_oval (120 ,180, 125, 185,fill ='blue')
#eye_left =c.create_oval (75 ,180, 80, 185,fill ='yellow')
eye_left = c.move(eye,-10,0)
mouth = c.create_line (145, 220, 120, 220,fill = 'red')
#mouth_left = c.create_line (55, 220, 80, 220,fill = 'blue')
hand =c.create_line (110, 300, 200, 220, fill = 'black')
GIRL_step = 10
def move_girl(event):
   if event.keysym == 'Up':
        c.move (body, 0, - GIRL_step)
        c.move (head, 0, - GIRL_step)
        c.move (eye, 0, - GIRL_step)
        c.move (mouth, 0, - GIRL_step)
        c.move (hand, 0, - GIRL_step)
    elif event.keysym== 'Down':
        c.move (body, 0, GIRL_step)
        c.move (head, 0, GIRL_step)
        c.move (eye, 0, GIRL_step)
        c.move (mouth, 0, GIRL_step)
        c.move (hand, 0, GIRL_step)
    elif event.keysym== 'Left':
        c.move(eye,-10, 0)
        c.move (body, - GIRL_step, 0)
        c.move (head, - GIRL_step, 0)
        c.move (eye, - GIRL_step, 0)
        c.move (mouth, _GIRL_step, 0)
        c.move (hand, - GIRL_step, 0)
    elif event.keysym== 'Right':
        c.move (body, GIRL_step, 0)
        c.move (head, GIRL_step, 0)
        c.move (eye, GIRL_step, 0)
        c.move (mouth, GIRL_step, 0)
        c.move (hand, GIRL_step, 0)
c.bind_all ('<Key>', move_girl )
```

Comment: You example does not work because of a type (underline instead of minus sign for eye in move "Left").  It works after correcting the typo.  Additionally you should test for move off of the face, x for eye is less than head x-radius of head for moving left.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can use a for() to make things easier

```
    for body_part in [body, head, eye, mouth, hand]:
        c.move (body_part, - GIRL_step, 0)
```

and a function to eliminate redundant code

```
from tkinter import *
HEIGHT = 500
WIDTH = 800
window = Tk()
window.title('Fetita arunca mingea')
c = Canvas (window, width = WIDTH, height = HEIGHT, bg = 'grey')
c.pack()
school= c.create_rectangle (200, 50,600, 150, fill = 'orange')
school_window1 = c.create_rectangle (250,80, 300, 100, fill= 'yellow')
school_window2 = c.create_rectangle (360,80, 420, 100, fill= 'yellow')
school_window2 = c.create_rectangle (500,80, 550, 100, fill= 'yellow')
body =c.create_polygon (0, 450, 250, 450, 100, 240,fill ='blue')
head = c.create_oval (50, 250, 150, 150, fill = 'ivory')
eye =c.create_oval (120 ,180, 125, 185,fill ='blue')
#eye_left =c.create_oval (75 ,180, 80, 185,fill ='yellow')
eye_left = c.move(eye,-10,0)
mouth = c.create_line (145, 220, 120, 220,fill = 'red')
#mouth_left = c.create_line (55, 220, 80, 220,fill = 'blue')
hand =c.create_line (110, 300, 200, 220, fill = 'black')
GIRL_step = 10

def move_common(move_x, move_y):
    for body_part in [body, head, eye, mouth, hand]:
        c.move (body_part, move_x, move_y)

def move_girl(event):
    if event.keysym == 'Up':
        move_common(0, -GIRL_step)
    elif event.keysym== 'Down':
        move_common(0, GIRL_ste)
    elif event.keysym== 'Left':
        c.move(eye,-10, 0)
        move_common(-GIRL_step, 0)
    elif event.keysym== 'Right':
        move_common(GIRL_step, 0)
c.bind_all ('<Key>', move_girl )

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your answer begins with "Also". "Also" to what? The answer implies there's a part 1 and a part 2, where this is part 2. Is part 1 the comment you made?